# GitHub - Undo action for browse the repository at this point in history

Tags: git, github, version-control

I'm using a corporate GitHub account in my organization. As I was browsing through the commit history I accidentally clicked on the `<>` button which said

[image]

I was on the `master` branch and suddenly the code commits history stopped after that day's commits. I tried to load the master branch code now, but it is still stopping on that day's commits

There were a whole month's updates which I'm not seeing now. The safe thing is I did not do any `commit`, `push` on the local or remote after this. So how would I safely undo this change to start seeing the last commit point.

Comment: There's nothing to undo as you've not changed anything. Instead you are just browsing at the point in history. Just browse back to `https://github.com/<user>/<repo>/tree/master`

Comment: @evolutionxbox: I already did that, but it is not getting back. The URL is still at `https://github.com/<user>/<repo>/tree/master` but the changes are pointing that day's history I reverted to. I hope I did not loose any changes. I did not make any commit to master

Comment: Try again in an incognito browser.

Comment: @evolutionxbox: No it isn't working, after clearing cache and browser history for the whole day

Comment: Are you sure you didn’t run any local commands like reset? You haven’t lost history, you just can’t seem to browse it on github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click **Browse the respsity at this point in the history**, github will show all the files version at that commit (similar as `git checkout commit` in the local repo).

You can check the URL will like `https://github.com/organizationName/reponame/tree/commit`

And it also show `Tree:commit` from the dropdown list:

[image]

**To switch to your latest `master` version**, you can use any of below options：

- **Option 1:** access to the URL as `https://github.com/organizationName/reponame`
- **Option 2:** select `master` branch from the dropdown list

  [image]

Comment: For some reason my changes were not showing up when I did those steps. Luckily the commits lost were on another branch and I was able to merge it to master easily.